# How do developers produce iOS Simulator animated .gifs?

Tags: ios, ios-simulator, gif

I often see this a lot on GitHub. How can I reproduce this animated .gif effect?

https://github.com/autresphere/ASMediaFocusManager

[image: animation]

Comment: check this: http://www.patridgedev.com/2013/09/27/capturing-your-ios-app-in-ios-simulator/

Comment: I thought this was a great question. Context is everything.

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/211219/35933

Comment: You can also use this https://github.com/onmyway133/GifCapture

Comment: Great question!

Comment: I did a small tool that achieves this. You can find it here: https://github.com/crvshlab/capa

Answer (score 77, accepted):

You can record your screen with QuickTime and then convert that MOV file into a GIF.

Open QuickTime and click on the "File" menu then "New Screen Recording".

[image]

Drag your pointer to select the region of the screen you want to record, and then click the Start Recording button within the region.

[image]

When you're finished, stop recording. To stop recording, click the stop button in the menu bar. Now, go back to "File" menu and click "Export".

[image]

Save your screen recording as a movie.

Next, you can use Photoshop to [open](http://www.briandalessandro.com/blog/convert-a-video-file-into-an-animated-gif-with-photoshop/) your screen recording and export it as a GIF.

Comment: A tiny bit more detail about how those things are done (or even a couple of links to websites explaining how to do it) would be really helpful here.

Comment: I'm having a hard time finding a way to capture just one window or selection at a time.

Comment: Added some pictures and better instructions.

Comment: If you don't have Photoshop you can use [this free site](http://www.zamzar.com/) instead

Comment: Just wanted to update this for every one not having Photoshop or just wants to make this in just a few seconds: Use the Giphy App , its free and painless. Has screen recording and saves as a gif by default. https://itunes.apple.com/de/app/giphy-capture.-the-gif-maker/id668208984?mt=12 - Not affiliated with them, just found this solution. It's easer..

Comment: There are some command line tools: `ffmpeg` and `gifsicle`.  See: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/211219/35933