# iOS Simulator Screen Recording with indicator

Tags: ios

Is there a way to record the screen of the iOS simulator and some sort of indicator? I basically want to replicate what Robinhood has done here: https://www.robinhood.com/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20078641/how-do-developers-produce-ios-simulator-animated-gifs

Comment: @Mikael If you inspect Robinhood.com's HTML code, you'll see that it's actually serving a video via an AWS S3 bucket. The answer in the post you linked to converts it to a GIF

Comment: you're right. However, in the link i sent to you, the very first step is to capture a video. You can just stop at that step,upload your video to S3 and read it from your website. The additional step using photoshop to create and animated gif is, indeed, unnecessary in your case.

Comment: @Mikael I want the little green indicator that they're using though. Do you see it? The thing that simulates a thumb on the screen.

Comment: I think that is post-edited. maybe with something like Adobe after effect. I don't think you can do it with things like iMovie. I think that Jing software (as indicated below) can display the mouse pointer while recording. Maybe they have different options for that. It might worth having a look at it

Answer (score -1):

Please download the Jing software from [here](https://www.techsmith.com/jing.html). By this you will be able to capture screencast of iOS Simulator.